# Trouble using react-pdf width Nextjs

Tags: next.js, react-pdf

I have an issue when i deploy my Nextjs App in production (OVH WEB Cloud).
I managed to display a pdf file (from an url) localy but when i move to production on my server, i have an error 500. I dont know what to do ?

```
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.min.js`;

function PostComics({ comics, locale }) {

  [...]
  return (
   
        <div className="frame">
          {comics?.data[0]?.attributes?.lien_pdf ? (
            <div
              style={{
                height: "100%",
                width: "100%",
                marginLeft: "auto",
                marginRight: "auto",
              }}
            >
              <Document
                file={comics?.data[0]?.attributes?.lien_pdf}
                onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
              >
                <Page pageIndex={indexPage} />
              </Document>

           [...]
  );
}
```

Thank you for your help.